# Trouble with EF6 inserts

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core, savechanges

I am in the process of Downgrading from EF7 to EF6 due to business decisions. I have looked at several examples but cannot seem to get it to work.

**Here is what I have for EF 7**

**Context:**

```
public class OwnerContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(@"Server=server\testdbs;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Owner>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Owner");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .HasColumnType("varchar");
            });
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Owner> Owner { get; set; }
    }
```

**Owner Model**

```
public class Owner
    {
        public int OwnerId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

**How I use it**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new OwnerContext())
        {
            var owner = new Owner
            {
                Name = "First Name",
                Age = 4
            };

            context.Owner.Add(owner);
            context.SaveChanges();

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
```

I got this to work with no issues and I get records in the data base. For EF 6 it is a little different

**Here is what I have for EF6**

**Context**

```
public class OwnerContext : DbContext
    {
        public OwnerContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }

    public OwnerContext()
        : this("OwnerConn")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Owner> Owner{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var owner = modelBuilder.Entity<Owner>().ToTable("Owner");

        owner.Property(e => e.OwnerId)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .HasColumnType("varchar");

        owner.HasKey(u => u.OwnerId);
    }

}
```

**Model**

```
public class Owner
        {
            public int OwnerId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
        }
```

**How I use it**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var context = new OwnerContext())
                {
                    var person = new Owner
                    {
                        Name = "Test Name",
                        Age = 5
                    };

                    context.Owner.Add(person);
                    context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Added;
                    context.SaveChanges();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

**ConnectionString**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="OwnerConn" connectionString="Server=server\testdbs;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

It seems to be very simple based on the tutorials. Hoever, I cant seem to get the changes to be reflected in the database. However, when I restart the console app and pull the records like this.

```
var rows = from a in context.Owner select a
```

It returns rows but I still don't see them in the DB. I'm out of ideas so hopefully someone can help.

Comment: Have you tried without setting .State? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I added that in the hopes that it would fix it based on a post I saw.

Comment: Try adding Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLn(s); to your constructor. That will show what EF is sending. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx